# libcurl/cURL c++ segfault

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to write a class to get some data from a website in C++ using cURL. Here's a sample from that class (there is a Curl* curl_ data member, rawData_ is a string). This excerpt is from the implementation file, all functions are declared in the header.

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_ = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_URL,
               "http://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &MyClass::writeCallback);

}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_);
    curl_global_cleanup();
}

size_t MyClass::writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{
    //buf is a pointer to the data that curl has for us
    //size*nmemb is the size of the buffer
    for (size_t c = 0; c<size*nmemb; ++c)
    {
        cerr << c << endl;
        rawData_.push_back(buf[c]);
    }
    return size*nmemb; //tell curl how many bytes we handled
}

void MyClass::makeCall()
{
    curl_easy_perform(curl_);
}
```

when I create an instance of MyClass and call makeCall, there is a segfault in the writeCallBack function. Namely, buf seems to be of size 0 (it breaks on the call of buf[c] when c = 0). Any help is appreciated

Comment: have you tested whether `buf == this`?

Comment: Is that something I should have to worry about? As far as I knew `buf` is something passed in by the web call; it should be basically the data from the website.

Comment: I was implying that, for C++ class methods, `this` can be thought as of being the implicit first argument of a static C-style function. If curl is calling your supplied callback as if it were a C-style function (which it is), at least the calling convention is not as C++ expects it in a class method when called, and undefined things happen.

Answer (score 5):

The parameter for `curl_easy_setopt` with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is supposed to be of type `size_t function( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)`. That's a "clean" C function, not a method.

But as far as I can see, you are passing the address of a non-static method. So it will not have the right signature (I'm guessing it's non-static because you are using `rawData_` inside it).

Now, `curl_easy_setopt` doesn't really care - it takes whatever you give it. But when it calls the function bad things will happen.

My suggestion would be to declare `writeCallback` as static (or even as a non-member friend) and set the userdata to `this` (using `curl_easy_setopt` with `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`). You can then cast the userdata parameter to `MyClass` and use it inside the function.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `curl_easy_setopt` is a variadic function and so is not able to check the function parameters for the correct types—otherwise, the compiler would assuredly give an error about not being able to convert a `size_t (X::*)(char*, size_t, size_t, void*)` to a `size_t (*)(char*, size_t, size_t, void*)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the libcurl manpage `curl_easy_setopt` where `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is explained, it states that the callback may be invoked with "zero size" on some occasions, such as to indicate an empty response.  In that case, at least the product of `size*nmemb` should be zero and thus your loop never entered with an empty buffer, so you should be safe there.

However, it also describes the parameter for `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` as taking a *function* with the given arguments, not a C++ member function.  It could very well be that your implicit `this` pointer within the callback member function body is being interpreted as `buf`.  It just so happens that `this` (internal class state) is dereferenced for the first time on the same line as your crash: `rawData_.push_back(buf[c])`.

Real quick, try converting your class member function callback to a static function callback (i.e., no longer a member of `MyClass`).  That should work.  Then you may either use this function as a `friend` to `MyClass`, or you may proxy a call to a class member function if you pass the appropriate `this` pointer to the `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` option when setting up your callback with `curl_easy_setopt`, allowing your static non-member function to invoke the appropriate C++ class method with the appropriate pointer to the class object.